# Firefox resets zoom-level

Tags: firefox

I upgraded Firefox to 75.0 (on Ubuntu 18.04), and since I upgraded, Firefox resets the zoom level on most sites.

When I go to a new site I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to set the zoom level. For years Firefox has remembered this zoom level, so when I return to the site, it starts at that zoom level.

After upgrading zoom level changes back to 100% if I simply change tab. What is even more surprising is that it does not do that for all sites (reddit.com is affected, but unix.stackexchange.com is not).

How can I have the old behaviour back?

Comment: did you search the about:config page for a setting named "*zoom*" ? Usually, when mozilla changes a default behaviour, they allow restoring previous one by an entry on about:config page.

Comment: Yep. I did. I found browser.zoom.siteSpecific which sounded right, but which did not change the behaviour. I tried both true and false. It was true originally.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the config page by typing **about:config** in a new tab. Enter *zoom* in the search box. Toggle **browser.zoom.siteSpecific** to **true**.

I tried it right now to test the solution and it works like a charm.

Comment: Mine is already set to true. I tried setting it to false. It did not help. And back to true. It did not change the behaviour either.

Comment: Well, that's odd, I reproduced your problem by toggling it to false. Toggled it back to true and it started working again. Let us know if you find the fix

Comment: @OleTange maybe it's some weird incompatibility with your profile? It might be worth trying with a different user or a different firefox profile. Maybe rename `~/.mozilla`?

Comment: Is your version 75.0 on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes it's 75.0 on Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: This did not work for me, either, sorry. When Firefox opens a new window from `example.com` to `example.com` by JavaScript, the zoom in the new window is reset to 100% irrespective of the calling tab's zoom setting.

Comment: Had the same problem with Firefox 78.0.2 (64-bit) on Manjaro Linux. `browser.zoom.siteSpecific` was already true. Toggling it to `false` and back to `true` fixed it for me!

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by Firefox's protection against fingerprinting which blocks site-specific zoom settings: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-protection-against-fingerprinting

`privacy.resistFingerprinting` must be `false` for the site-specific zoom functionality to function.

This can be especially annoying for sites that sync their theme (like github and  duckduckgo) to the theme of the browser. I like my browser to always use a dark theme but during the day I don't want those sites to be dark too. Enabling fingerprint restriction solves that but as it turns out it breaks other behaviour.

Comment: Alternatively you can add the site to your `privacy.resistFingerprinting.exemptedDomains` setting, that will enable the site-specific zoom just for that site.